# Регулярное выражение для замены пробелов на переносы строк по условию

Tags: javascript, html, регулярные-выражения

Есть функция:

```
function chistka() {
  var s = document.getElementById('raspuns').value;

  var ri = /(>)\s(<)/gmi;
  var re = /$1\n$2/;

  var result = s.replace(ri, re);
  document.getElementById('raspuns').value = result;
}
```

Требование: Переводить строки если в HTML-коде есть пробелы между тегами/символами `>` и `<`

Например: Найти `> <` и заменить на `>`*перевод строки*`<`

Проблема в том, что при замене получается `/>\n< /` т.е. распознаётся как текст, а не как регулярное выражение.

Результат:

```
<style type="text/css"/>\n</!-- span.cls_004{font-family:Arial,serif;font-size:18.1px;color:rgb(255,255,255);font-weight:bold;font-style:normal;text-decoration: none} --/>\n<//style/>\n</div style="position:absolute;left:50%;margin-left:-306px;top:0px;width:612px;height:792px;border-style:outset;overflow:hidden"/>\n</div style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px"/>\n</img src="Utah motorcycleFactSheet2012_files/background1.jpg" width=612 height=792></div/>\n</div style="position:absolute;left:29.88px;top:32.86px" class="cls_004"><span class="cls_004">2012 Utah Crash Facts</span></div/>\n<//div>
```

[Пример на Codepen](http://codepen.io/mihail9575/pen/nfjAF)

```js
function chistka() {
  var s = document.getElementById('raspuns');
  var result = s.value.replace(/(>)\s(<)/gmi, '$1\n$2');
  s.value = result;
}
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 50%;
  height: 170px;
}
```

```html
<textarea value="" id="raspuns">&lt;style type="text/css"&gt; &lt;!-- span.cls_004{font-family:Arial,serif;font-size:18.1px;color:rgb(255,255,255);font-weight:bold;font-style:normal;text-decoration: none} --&gt; &lt;/style&gt; &lt;div style="position:absolute;left:50%;margin-left:-306px;top:0px;width:612px;height:792px;border-style:outset;overflow:hidden"&gt; &lt;div style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px"&gt; &lt;img src="Utah motorcycleFactSheet2012_files/background1.jpg" width=612 height=792&gt;&lt;/div&gt; &lt;div style="position:absolute;left:29.88px;top:32.86px" class="cls_004"&gt;&lt;span class="cls_004"&gt;2012 Utah Crash Facts&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt;</textarea><br />
<button onclick="chistka();">ok</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте так:

```
function chistka() {
  var s = document.getElementById('k2').value;
  var ri = /(>)\s(<)(\n)/gmi;

  var result = s.replace(ri, "$1\n$2");
  document.getElementById('k2').value = result;
}
```

У вас \n не интерпретируется как символ переноса строки.